# Reason for exception - added item does not appear at given index

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a `ICollectionView` in my viewmodel binded to `DataGrid` in view. When I perform Add/Delete operation. I get this exception.

I can't change the `CollectionView`. Can anyone tell me the reason for this exception so that may be I can find out the solution for this.

Exception:

> "Added item does not appear at given index"

Stack Trace:

> at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.AdjustBefore(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
>      at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.CommitNew()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CommitRowItem()
>      at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedCommitEdit(ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, CommandBinding commandBinding)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(CommandBindingCollection commandBindings, Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, ICommand command, Boolean execute)
>      at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
>      at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
>      at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
>      at System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(Object parameter, IInputElement target, Boolean userInitiated)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.EndEdit(RoutedCommand command, DataGridCell cellContainer, DataGridEditingUnit editingUnit, Boolean exitEditMode)
>      at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnCurrentCellChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

Thanks

Comment: You get what exception? Seems like you lost something along the way.

Comment: "added item does not appear at given index" is the exception I get.

Answer (score 1):

while i had the same issue "Added item does not appear at given index '0'
i was searching for it and found this unsolved post.

in my personal file i was providing data's to the collescion asynchon so everything i had to do is add an SynchronizationContext into it.

and us it so before i populated the observablecollection with results i simply had to:

```
 _synchronizationContext.Acquire();
 (ObservableCollectionName).Add(YourItem);
 _synchronizationContext.Release();
```

even if this is an old post i hope it will help at least somebody else :=)